# How to have Artifactory provide the same artifact checksums as registry.npmjs.org?

Tags: node.js, npm, artifactory, integrity

When switching to Artifactory the npm install produces the package-lock.json file with only SHA1 digests for artifacts checksums. Without Artifactory (i.e. using registry.npmjs.org) npm combines SHA1 and SHA512 (latter is used for packages published with npm version 5 and above, according to npm community). Is there a configuration option to use SHA512 vs SHA1?

Comment: I'm having issues with packages flip-flopping between sha1 and sha512. causes lockfile conflicts that are really annoying on a big team. Would love a way to force one or the other.